# Given $a= 4bc,\ a =100,\ b=2$, work out the value of $c$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've come up with 12.5 because that multiplied by 2 is 25 and 25 times 4 is a hundred.

Am I correct by doing this? Sorry if it's a stupid question.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Yes, you are correct - $c=12.5$. Notice that $\displaystyle a=4bc\implies c=\frac{a}{4b}=\frac{100}{4\times 2}=12.5$.

Comment: Don't think that your question is stupid. Here is the place for math questions at any level. If you just show sufficient effort, then you will be welcome.

Comment: It's not a stupid question.  But *how* do work it out?  Did you just try and guess until you found something that worked.  Or did you work out with logic and algebra what it must be?  [Placing a =100 and b = 2 into the first equation gives us 100 = 4\*2\* c.  Do you see where to go from there?]

Comment: i jus guessed to be honest with you

Answer (score 1):

$$100=4\cdot2c\Longleftrightarrow 100=8c\Longleftrightarrow c=\frac{100}{8}\Longleftrightarrow c=\frac{25}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have $a=4bc$ but immediately know $a=100$ and $b=2$.  Substituting you get 
$$
100=4(2)c
$$
or
$$ 100 = 8c $$
Divide both sides by 8 and you get the 12.5 you suggested
$$ \frac{25}{2}=c$$

Answer (score 0):

So rearrange your first equation:

$a\div 4b = c$

Now just substitute your values for $b$ and $c$ into the rearranged equation.